# Edmond's theorem for k-disjoint arborescences in digraphs

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees, directed-graphs

Recently while studying arborescences in graph theory, I came across Edmond's theorem for $k$ edge-disjoint arborescences in digraphs

> if a finite digraph is $k$ edge-connected from a vertex r for some $k \in N$, then it has
> $k$ edge-disjoint spanning arborescences rooted at $r$

Now, I do understand what is meant by arborescence and $k$ edge-disjoint arborescences in a digraph. My question is, what is the meaning of $k$ edge-connected from $r$? I am unable to visualize it. If someone can explain with the help of a diagram, it would be great.